# Mejorar rendimiento al unir dos array segun id

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Tengo la siguiente tabla de registro de VENTAS con mas de 2500 filas y que sigue aumentando..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta tabla la columna `ordenArt` es el ID del articulo que se debo vincular a otras dos tablas, ya sea STOCK DE ACCESORIO (VAC) O EQUIPOS (VE)

Cuando realizo la consulta al server, necesito unir las tablas para devolver un nuevo array.
En este código muestro como concateno las tablas de registros de `VENTAS` con los STOCK de accesorios y equipos

**OPCIÓN 1:**

```
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      let historial_transc_ventas = libro.getSheetByName('VENTAS').getDataRange().getValues();
      historial_transc_ventas = historial_transc_ventas.slice(1, historial_transc_ventas.length);
    
      let equipos_disponibles = libro.getSheetByName('STOCK_EQUIPOS').getDataRange().getValues();
      let accesorios_disponibles = libro.getSheetByName('STOCK_ACCESORIOS').getDataRange().getValues();
    
      historial_transc_ventas.forEach((col, i) => {
        if (col[7] === 'VE') {
          let equipo = equipos_disponibles.find(e => e[1] === col[8])
          if (equipo[0]) historial_transc_ventas[i].push(equipo[2],equipo[10],equipo[3],equipo[4],equipo[5])
          else historial_transc_ventas[i].push('-','-','-','-','-')
        }
    
        if (col[7] === 'VAC') {
          let accs = accesorios_disponibles.find(e => e[0] === col[8])
          historial_transc_ventas[i].push(accs[2],accs[3],accs[4],'-','-')
        }
      })

return historial_transc_ventas;
```

Con esta opción el servidor tarda aprox 2.7seg en unir.
Probé con una opción de unir mediante objetos para eliminar los métodos `find`.

**OPCIÓN 2**

```
function _dataObj(sheet,rowID) {
  let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let header = data.shift();

  let result = {}

  data.forEach((row, indx) => {   
    let id = String(row[rowID]);
    let reduced = header.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) => {
      accumulator[currentValue] = row[currentIndex];
      return accumulator;
    }, {});
    reduced.row = indx + 2;
    result[id] = reduced;
    return reduced;
  });

  return result;
}

    function ReadTransVENTAS(){

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
          let historial_transc_ventas = libro.getSheetByName('VENTAS').getDataRange().getValues();
          historial_transc_ventas = historial_transc_ventas.slice(1, historial_transc_ventas.length);
    
          let equipos_disponibles = libro.getSheetByName('STOCK_EQUIPOS')
          let accesorios_disponibles = libro.getSheetByName('STOCK_ACCESORIOS')
    
          let equipos_JSON = _dataObj(equipos_disponibles,1);
          let accesorios_JSON = _dataObj(accesorios_disponibles,0);
    
          historial_transc_ventas.forEach((col, i) => {
            if (col[7] === 'VE') {
              let dataEquipos = equipos_JSON[String(col[8])]          
              if (dataEquipos) historial_transc_ventas[i].push(dataEquipos.modelo,dataEquipos.condicionActual,dataEquipos.color,dataEquipos.capacidad,dataEquipos.imei)
              else historial_transc_ventas[i].push('-','-','-','-','-')
            }
    
            if (col[7] === 'VAC') {
              let dataAccs = accesorios_JSON[String(col[8])]                  
              historial_transc_ventas[i].push(dataAccs.modelos,dataAccs.descripcion,dataAccs.color,'-','-')
            }
          })
return historial_transc_ventas;
     }
```

Con la opción 2, no hubo mucho cambio en el tiempo de ejecución, pasando a 2.3seg.
No hubo muchos cambios con este método.

A) Que método es más eficiente?

B) El método push ralentiza la ejecución con el ForEach?

C) Debería usar Map en lugar de ForEach?

Comment: Yo probaría con [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) a ver si mejora el rendimiento.

Comment: No está claro porque estás usando `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` . Te sugiero agregar un [mcve] y para efectos de benchmarking considera aislar tus funciones complemente de la interacción con la hoja de cálculo al menos asegúrate que las mediciones de tiempo no se "contaminen" por estas.